# Gauge Gravitation Theory

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory

Gauge gravitation theory seems to be a consistent framework for gravity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_gravitation_theory

Can anyone here explain how this theory this works, using an example in 2D?

Comment: More on [GR as a gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity+gauge-theory).

Comment: @Qmechanic None of the previous questions talk about this specific flavour of gauge gravitational theory. I checked.